# Is it necessary to use quotes in KDE4 ServiceMenus?

Tags: kde4, servicemenu

In the `Exec=` line of a service menu in kde4, I normally use:

`Exec=command %f`

So I wonder, if it's necessary to quote the `%f`, not sure how KDE4 parses the menu file, i.e

`Exec=command "%f"`

Answer (score 0):

I've found several threads where people have included the quotes around the arguments in the `Exec=` lines. I believe you need them if the arguments you're dealing with include spaces.

For example this thread titled: [shell scripting basics.. how to forward double quotes ??](http://linux.error-exception.org/article/1347354/shell+scripting+basics..+how+to+forward+double+quotes+??).

*excerpt*

> I'm trying to make servicemenu entry to kde what unrar:s files I
>   select.  I put this to servicemenu file:
>
> ```
> Exec=/usr/bin/extract 1 %U
> ```
>
> and in /usr/bin/extract I have:
>
> ```
> if [ $1 = "1" ]; then
>     unrar e "$2"
> fi  
> if [ $1 = "2" ]; then
>     unrar x "$2"
> fi
> ```
>
> It works fine except if filename includes spaces.

So it would appear that you can get away with not using quotes unless you're dealing with either:

- paths that includes spaces
- file names that include spaces
- command line arguments that includes spaces.